# iOS develop & test from one account, but publish from other

Tags: ios

I need to know if I can use my developer account to develop application and test it. Than later publish from other account?

If I will add application to my account for testing will I be able to publish it from other account?

I have read that it is possible to test application on up to 100 devices. Personally I won't have access to real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only apples paid account ($99) for test application. To test application you must need provisioning profile and certificate with test device id's. without provisioning profile your application will not get installed on the device. You have to use paid account. only developer account will not help you

Comment: I do understand that I have to use paid account, but that is not problem. Will I be able to publish application from other account if that application will be added to my account for testing?